# Parse JSON Array without key in Android Using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have to Parse a JSON Array without key in Android Using Retrofit. There is no key, I'm getting value only.

[
55,
10,
105,
30,
5,
6,
12,
100
]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. The code you wrote

Answer (score 2):

Your data type is `List<Int>` or `List<Long>`

```kotlin
interface HttpService {
    @GET("/path/of/your/api")
    suspend fun getMyValues(): List<Int>
}
```